# Music won't play in Firefox

Tags: audio, mp3, ogg

The site is http://www.kingcharltonmusic.com/album/wednesday-overproof-riddim-2/

I am using a plugin that asks for mp3 and ogg versions of the file. For some reason, every other browser uses the mp3, but firefox looks for the ogg and then I get some sort of error and it won't play. Here is the error:

HTTP "Content-Type" of "text/html" is not supported. Load of media resource http://www.kingcharltonmusic.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/Wednesday-ogg1.ogg failed. @ http://www.kingcharltonmusic.com/album/wednesday-overproof-riddim-2/

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it looks like firefox is having a hard time with the OGG mime type and is trying to read it as html. You should try to force the content-type header to mp3 or ogg when you're serving up a file like that.

Comment: According to what I've found this is the answer. I just don't know how to force it

Comment: what is the programming language you're serving the music with?

Comment: The plugin that plays the music is written in php. Is it something I have to add there, or something I add to the header? (or even something server side?)

Comment: I just had to go onto my server and add the audio/ogg MIME for .ogg files. It was a setting on the server itself. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I use [Buzz.js](http://buzz.jaysalvat.com/) for playing music, you still have to provide a mp3 file as well as an ogg one, but it solves your problem and works on every browser.